# Pandas/Python Converting a series with two columns into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, series

My question is pretty simple but I haven't found an answer for it anywhere on stackexchange or google. In pandas for python, how do you convert a series with two columns back into a dataframe? My series (agggenfreq) is below.
The code that generated it was this:

```
agggenfreq=df2000[['freq','name','sex']].groupby(['name', 'sex']).sum()['freq']
```

Where df2000 is a dataframe containing the following columns:

```
 name sex   freq  year     agg
 0  Hannah   F  23071  2000  162834
 1  Hannah   M     25  2000  162834
 2  Hannah   F  20706  2001  162834
 3  Hannah   M     22  2001  162834
 4  Hannah   F  18814  2002  162834
```

agggenfreq:

```
 name       sex
 Aaden      F          5
            M       2980
 Aaliah     F        518
 Aaliya     F        583
 Aaliyah    F      40975
            M         49
 Aamir      M        607
 Aaniyah    F        741
 Aanya      F        954
 Aaralyn    F        581
 Aarav      M       1374
 Aaron      F        365
            M      94269
 Aarush     M        763
 Aarya      F        375
            M        190
 Aaryan     M        560
 Aaryn      F        293
            M        272
 Aayush     M        632
 Abagail    F       3051
 Abbey      F       5230
            M          6
```

Is there a good way to convert this back into a dataframe? If there was only one column (which I think technically isn't the correct term but you should know what I mean) in the series here I would do it like this:

data = pd.DataFrame({'agg': aggfreq,'name':aggfreq.index})

How do I do this with two columns?
Thanks in advance.
EDIT: Also if someone knows of a better way to do the abovementioned (first) function in-line without having to make a series I would love to know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a Series with a MultiIndex.  You can get a DataFrame by doing `agggenfreq.reset_index()`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what the two indices are? I assume 'name' is one but is 'sex' one too?

Comment: Yes.  Because you grouped on name and sex, those are both indices (or rather, levels of the MultiIndex).  You can read more about MultiIndexes in [their documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex) and [the groupby documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the fast response. That helps. Resetting the index totally made it work. Thanks!

Comment: Actually there is one problem with the reset index method. It puts all the data into the dataframe as one column. That is not quite what I am looking for. Sorry, I unaccepted the answer because I am still where I was before.

Comment: @user3314282: What do you mean "as one column"?  Can you give an example of the output you want?

Comment: Oh! I actually just figured it out, I was calling the reset_index() function but never assigning it to anything. Can I retract my earlier statement? The reset index method does work. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @BrenBarn is correct. If you want to avoid creating a MultiIndex in the first place, you can run 
`agggenfreq = df2000.groupby(['name', 'sex'], as_index=False).freq.sum()`
which gives you a DataFrame as a result.

The `as_index=False` flag expands the grouping variables into columns. I also simplified the command.